# Importing classes from prefix.pch

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am facing an issue, Currently i am using xcode 5.0, when i am importing clasess from prefix.pch then it dose not give suggestions on appdelegate.h file. But it gives suggestion on other view controller's. I have googled about it and find if we define macros in prefix.pch then this problem occurred. Still after removing the macros it did not give suggestion on appdelegate.
Suggestios means if i try to write

```
 @property(strong,nonatomic) UINavigationController *navControler;
```

After writing `@property(strong,nonatomic) UINav` xcode did not give suggestion. But if I remove all the import statement and macros from prefix.pch file then xcode give suggestions on appdelegate.

[image]

Comment: which file does not give you response ??

Comment: @iPatel on RootviewAppDelegate.h if i try to write UINvigat then xcode should give suggestions like UINavigationController, UiNavigationbar, UINavigationItem...etc but it is not showing me.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I am also facing the same issue in xcode 5 if adds #define in .pch file. when remove all #import and #define then it works.

Comment: @Rinku :Look at the approach in my answer for including `#define`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my point of view, rather than finding a workaround, I want to put some light on the actual problem.

So when you want to add something in .pch (pre compiled headers), it means you want to use the content of files before your program is actually being compiled & build. In simple words the headers included in pch acts as a stub code, a base code or may be a code that is meant for using as it is intact.

So if you have already included `appDelegate.h` file in .pch & writing some code in `appDelegate.h` file, then the compiler is trying to use 'appDelegate.h` from .pch as a pre-compiled information. And may be it is resulting in a indefinite sate of Xcode background processing, which is not allowing to show the drop down helps in the file which is already pre-compiled.

To me it looks like `app delegate.h` in .pch is not the right place. Where ever you want in your program, you can very well include `appDelegate.h` file. However it is also a signal of bad Class Design approaches.

Also, if you want to add `#define` statement & other macros in `.pch` then it is not the right approach. The right approach is :

1. Make a simple .h file, say `constants.h`
2. Add all your `#defines & macros` here in `constants.h` file.
3. Add the `#import "constants.h"` in your `.pch` file.
4. That should solve your problem.

Hope that helps.